# Sharding a MongoDB database having a Tree Structure

Tags: mongodb, sharding, horizontal-scaling, tree-structure

I have a MongoDB collection having a Tree Structure and need to use sharding. I couldn't find anything specific to Tree Structures in the documentation on Sharding. If anybody can let me know how to approach this, that'd be great.
Thank you.

Comment: By default, indexes in MongoDB is B-tree structure. So when you use sharding, it's actually already stores as Tree structure.

Comment: Thank you @Valijon. Do you know how to go about setting shard keys for a tree structure?

Comment: Can you post sample data? You don't need to save as Tree structure, you can build it querying with [$graphLookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/index.html#considerations)